# Symfony2 Form is waiting for submitted fields names be inside array with form identifier

Tags: symfony

I did read The Symfony's Book about [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html) and did not find any answer related to naming of form parameters. My situation:

I am trying to implement simple REST application with native Symfony2 framework.
I have a controller where I use Form Class to manage all stuff. It looks like this one:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $task = ...;
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    // ...
}
```

My form class is:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('task')
            ->add('dueTask')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add gift'))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

And I have a JavaScript client who able to sends POST requests to my API (in this case create a new task). **So my questions are**:

**Main question**: I have to send parameters in request named **task[task]** and **task[dueTask]**. But I do not want it. I do not want to depend on form name. but without providing proper form name my forms behave like invalid. How can I manage it?

*Optional question*: What is the **best practice to protect my APIs** when application is RESTfull ? As you can see I switched off [csrf protection](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#forms-csrf). How can I share some secret between client side (Mobile application) and server side (Symfony2).

Thank you.

Comment: Using the form component may not be your best choice especially if you want to change the element names.  The form component is "highly" engineered and challenging to understand.  On the other hand, it is very configurable and you could probably dive into the code and see where the element names are being generated and adjust accordingly.  But it might be best to just use your own system.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use the give form identifiers?

Comment: It is not a problem to use given form identifiers but it is more complicated to manage incoming parameters and specification as one example. Instead of focusing on just parameters I have also remember (and know) form name as well.

Comment: 1. use `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, 'task'); 2. use https

Comment: When it comes to API protection there is one interesting article: https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/